# Split single row in dataframe to multiply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

The data I have right now is structured as lists in a single row of a dataframe and I'd like to break it into multiple rows. What I'm working with now:
[image: Dataframe Snippet]

and the ideal outcome would be:

```
0                   CCDC160      CYTH3    ......    
1                   6.5656       8.9028 
2                   6.2135       7.9683   .......
.                      .                .
.                      .                 .
1000               5.6789       6.6787   ......
```

multiple splits into arrays were not working out for me.

Comment: Will you please send the result of `print(type(df.loc['SeqData', 0]))` ?

Comment: Actually, rather provide `df.to_dict()`. Also, any reason why you use a wide layout? Or not the Gene_Name as column ID?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.concat`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.drop('SeqData'), pd.DataFrame(df.loc['SeqData'].tolist()).T])
```

Comment: Clever on two counts: use of `drop()` as well as the transpose (`T`). Also remarkably succinct.

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you Richard and everyone else contributing!

Answer (score 1):

You could use explode to explode list to rows. See example below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'def'],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]], columns=['0','1'])
print(df)
print(df.explode(['0','1']))
```

**Output:**

```
           0          1
0        abc        def
1  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]


     0    1
0  abc  def
1    1    4
1    2    5
1    3    6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to unroll the lists with output that looks roughly like that specified in the question:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gene_Name': ['CCDC160', 'CYTH3'],
    'P_value': [0.000003, 0.000026],
    'SeqData': [[6.5656, 6.2135, 5.5387], [8.9028, 7.9683, 8.8132]]
}).T
print(df)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*list(y for y in df.loc['SeqData']))), columns=df.loc['Gene_Name'].tolist())
print('\n', df)
```

Output:

```
                                  0                         1
Gene_Name                   CCDC160                     CYTH3
P_value                    0.000003                  0.000026
SeqData    [6.5656, 6.2135, 5.5387]  [8.9028, 7.9683, 8.8132]

    CCDC160   CYTH3
0   6.5656  8.9028
1   6.2135  7.9683
2   5.5387  8.8132
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Manjunath K Mayya post, I added reset_index so row index is reset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'def'],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]], columns=['0','1'])
print(df)
print(df.explode(['0','1']).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
           0          1
0        abc        def
1  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]

     0    1
0  abc  def
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6
```